# problemas con el scroll, me salen dos scrollbar

Tags: css, scroll

Tengo el siguiente caso, que en mi aplicación tengo dos scroll, como hago para que solo salga uno, el que esta adentro.

[image: Dos Scrollbar]

**PD:** No me llevo con css.

Comment: Si no conoces nada de css, es hora de empezar a estudiarlo ya que no podras solucionarlo, como dicen `overflow-y: hidden` solucionaria tu problema, pero debes de saber donde poner dicho codigo. Porque no haces clik derecho encima del scroll que no te gusta y muestras una foto del codigo que te salga.

Answer (score 1):

Se agrega overflow hidden al elemento que esta generando el scroll, en este caso el scroll de afuera es el que el navegador te genera cuando el sitio es demasiado largo; podrías probar con agregarselo al body

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Si utilizo el `overflow: hidden`. No es visible el pie(la flechita que apunta de abajo que tiene el scroll) del scroll "hijo", queda como escondido

Comment: Si es lo malo de ocultar ese scroll, lo que podrías hacer es darle un alto fijo al elemento que contiene el scroll que sería algo como .div{ height: 100px }, recuerda que el scroll que ocultaste es el que se utiliza normalmente para scrollear los sitios

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que querrás eliminar el scroll interior.

Ese scroll te aparece ya que le has puesto límite de altura a ese elemento, como no puede crecer más a lo alto, le aparece un scroll.

El "overflow: hidden" esconde el scroll y todo lo que sobresalga de ese elemento, pero lo correcto en tu caso es quitar la limitación de altura.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un "height: 100vh", el alto de esa caja será el 100% del alto de la ventana, por lo que todo lo demás se verá con scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
--overflow: hidden;
```

en donde quieras eliminar el scroll pero siempre en el css

ejemplo en ionic:

```
ion-content { --overflow: hidden;}
```